# iphone online leader board

Tags: iphone

i'm trying to use one of the online iphone leader boards for my app.

I found iphonelb.com but they seem to only accept numerical score values,
whereas I need to upload string and the number of occurences of that string.
Implementing the board myself might be the best way, but it requires too much time and new learning time, so I'm leaning towards using online sources.

Any recommendation for my app's need?
doesn't have to be a free resource (of course, it's better if so).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [**OpenFeint**](http://openfeint.com/)?